# This certificate has an invalid digital signature

Tags: tls, certificates, x.509

I am trying to learn securing wcf service using ssl. I found this website and I am following the steps. http://robbincremers.me/2011/12/27/wcf-transport-security-and-client-certificate-authentication-with-self-signed-certificates/. But when came to creating certificate step I had an issue. Using below to create a certificate.

```
makecert –pe –n “CN=localhost” –sr localmachine –ss my –sky exchange
```

By default, the makecert utility creates certificates whose root authority is "Root Agency".  For some reason, my Root Agency cert has become corrupted (invalid digital signature).  How can I restore a valid Root Agency cert?

The site says when I create a certificate using above statement and double click on it I should see this

[image]

But I am seeing this:

[image]

So even If I add Root Agency to trusted root certificate authority it doesn't make any sense.

Other screenshot from my guide site:
[image]

And I have

[image]

How can I fix "This certificate has an invalid digital signature" issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could be due to the length restrictions on certificate keys.

Microsoft enforced a minimum key length limit of 1024 bits in August 2012. Check that your self signed cert is created with a key length of at least 1024 bits.

For more info you can check out this blog post [What does the “This certificate has an invalid digital signature.” message actually mean?](http://morgansimonsen.wordpress.com/2013/05/30/what-does-the-this-certificate-has-an-invalid-digital-signature-message-actually-mean/)

You can specify the key length when creating the cert with by using the `-len` parameter like so:

```
makecert -pe -ss MY -$ individual -n "CN=your name here" -len 2048 -r
```

Comment: Exactly this reason with Windows 10 and Openssl.

Comment: I have the same issue with trusted root and parent CA, but with a public key "RSA (2048 Bits)"...is there a new restriction added recently that forces greater key lenghts?

Comment: It's difficult to say for certain from the information you have provided but I don't see any explicit mention that the key size requirement is greater that 2048 for CA Roots (at least according to most recent CAB Forum baseline requirements). I did see that the requirement for Code Signing certs is been upped to >= 3072 bits somewhere in 2021. Does your certificate perhaps have the Code signing extension enabled?

Anyway, this is not a Q&A section - perhaps consider making this a separate question if you need more answers.

Answer (score 3):

you can run following command in a command prompt (with administrative rights):

```
certutil -setreg chain\minRSAPubKeyBitLength 512
```

this will set back the required key length (less secure!)

see https://morgansimonsen.wordpress.com/2013/05/30/what-does-the-this-certificate-has-an-invalid-digital-signature-message-actually-mean/ for more information.

quote from this website:

> The reason is to be found in the Public Key Length field. In this
>   certificate the public key is only 512 bytes. In August of 2012
>   Microsoft released an update that will block any certificates with RSA
>   keys less than 1024 bits in length. This was done to make sure that a
>   private key cannot be discovered using brute force methods and thus
>   exposing private information. After the update the CryptoAPI, which
>   builds a certificate trust chain and validates that chain by using
>   time validity, certificate revocation, and certificate policies (such
>   as intended purposes), implements an additional check to make sure
>   that no certificate in the chain has an RSA key length of less than
>   1024 bits. Any such certificates will not be trusted. Actually the
>   error displayed by Internet Explorer; “The security certificate
>   presented by this web site is not secure” makes more sense than the
>   messages in the certificate properties (“This certificate has an
>   invalid digital signature”). Because that is actually what is
>   happening; the certificate is not good enough to protect whatever data
>   your are transmitting between the client and the server. So how come,
>   according to the CryptoAPI extension, the digital signature is not
>   valid? In public key cryptography the private key is generated from
>   the public keys, or rather, the very large prime numbers selected to
>   be the public key. That means that if the public key is weak, i.e.
>   less than 512 bytes, the resulting private key would be as well. Since
>   it is the issuing authority’s private key that is used to sign the
>   issued certificate the signature itself would also be weak. And that
>   is why the CryptoAPI displays the message “This certificate has an
>   invalid digital signature”. What it should have displayed is something
>   along the lines of “this certificates was signed with a weak private
>   key etc.”. If you are desperate to use certificates with key lengths
>   less than 1024 bits you can override the restrictions imposed by the
>   Microsoft update. How to do that is documented in the KB article
>   accompanying the update. Here is the command I ran to test that I was
>   on the right track and force IE to let me use the certificate.